# REGEXP BINARY sql syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have this `$value= 24153;`
I have a field that can hold one or more values like this `{"id":"2","value":["3"]}` or like this `{"id":"2","value":["3","4"]}` or `{"id":"2","value":["3","4","2"]}`
I have this regex that works fine, but returns if the ONE value exists.
I need to improve this regex to the case there are more than one value in field.

```
REGEXP BINARY \'(.*{"id":"2","value":\["[^\"]*['.$value.'][^\"]*",?)+\]}.*\'
```

Comment: -1 for storing JSON in the database and then searching through using REGEXP. The only idea of this makes me sick.

Answer (score 0):

here is a regexp that will do what you want - but i have to agree with Your Common Sense - storing json and then using regex to extract data from it is sickening

```
REGEXP BINARY \'(.*{"id":"2","value":\[("[^\"]*",)*"'.$value.'"(,"[^\"]*")*)+\]}.*\'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$value = 4;
$subject_a = '{"id":"2","value":["4"]}';
$subject_b = '{"id":"2","value":["1","4","1","1"]}';
$subject_c = '{"id":"2","value":["1","1","1","1","1","44","1","1"]}';
$pattern = '/{"id":"2","value":\[("|\d|,)*"' . $value . '"("|\d|,)*\]/';

$matches[0] = preg_match($pattern,$subject_a);
$matches[1] = preg_match($pattern,$subject_b);
$matches[2] = preg_match($pattern,$subject_c);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result will be:

```
array(3) {
   [0]=> int(1)
   [1]=> int(1)
   [2]=> int(0)
}
```

Comment: ok here is the old query which return results SELECT ... AND extra_fields REGEXP BINARY '(.*{"id":"2","value":\["[^\"]*[1][^\"]*",?)+\]}.*' ORDER BY i.id DESC but only based on $subject_a structure . this is the new query which returns nothing! SELECT ...  AND extra_fields REGEXP BINARY '{"id":"2","value":\[("|\d|,)*"1"("|\d|,)*\]' ORDER BY i.id DESC

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP BINARY           '{"id":"2","value":\[[0-9",]*"4"[0-9",]*\]}';                                                   assuming 4 is your value